Why is filtered square wave output ~10% higher than half of peak voltage?

As we can see in the simulation, the voltage stabilizes at 550 volts instead of the expected 500. Why is that the case?

Show the input waveform and output waveforms together. Don't use node numbers, use labels.

If I showed the 1kV 1MHz input waveform the graph would just be cluttered and provide no useful information.

Why do you have the diode? Why do you not have another diode to 1000 V?

@CL The diode does nothing but clutter the diagram since it's connected right across an ideal voltage source.

It doesn't work without a diode :)

Your average input voltage is 550V, so the output is as-expected.
This is because by setting '0' you've used the default rise and fall times for the 'pulse' function, which are as follows:

LTspice automatically will use a default value for  and 
if these parameters are set to zero.  Default value: 10% of Ton or 10%
of Tperiod-Ton whatever is smaller.  You must specify Trise and Tfall
if you want a certain value.

You can set them to something like 1ns.
What you have:

If the waveform was symmetrical about ground the added rise and fall times would average out, but it's not symmetrical.

GREAT catch, and it took me some time to analyze your answer. I had always assumed that equal rise and fall times would still give equal Ton and Toff, which added to my confusion.

However, it seems that it adds to Ton and takes away from Toff. Is this what really happens in a practical circuit? Sorry for two messages, the system only gives 5 minutes to edit comments, and mine timed out.
